# Deleting duplicate rows with condition(Using SQL and LINQ)

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a table with 5 columns`ID,CPT4,CPT4Mod,ItemCharge,Eff_Date`.

**Deletion Condition:**

When rows exists with duplicate `CPT4`and `CPT4Mod` field values but different `ItemCharge` and `Eff_Date` values, exclude all but the most recent Eff_Date records.

I need a query which can achieve this in two scenarios.

1. When `CPT4Mod` is given by the user.
2. When  `CPT4Mod` is not given by the user.

Later I need to achieve the same using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH KeepLatest AS
(
  SELECT *, 
     RANK() OVER (
       PARTITION BY CPT4,CPT4Mod
       ORDER BY Eff_Date DESC, ItemCharge) as Rnk
  FROM dbo.YourTable
 )
 DELETE KeepLatest
 WHERE Rnk > 1
 ;
```

By using `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` you will avoid deleting anything if you have a row which is identical across all four columns - although I'm not sure why you'd want that.

If you know the `CPT4Mod` value, include: `AND CPT4Mod = @CPT4Mod`

Answer (score 1):

You can learn from this example :

```
create table dbo.ProductsCount (prdid int , cnt int)
go

insert into dbo.ProductsCount (prdid, cnt)
select 111,2
union all 
select 111,5
union all
select 112,10
union all
select 112,20
go

select *
from dbo.ProductsCount
order by prdid;
go

-- delete duplicates with CTE and ROW_NUMBER()

; WITH C AS
    (
    select prdid,cnt,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY prdid order by (select null) ASC) RN
    from dbo.ProductsCount
    )
delete C 
where RN > 1
go
```

Comment: Not able to replicate my scenario with above example. Can you bring more clarity to your answer.

Comment: do you want to delete duplicate rows ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to leave the one with latest Eff_Date. One more thing(the deletion criteria is that first two columns should match, but the later two should be different compulsorily)